# Распознания речи аудио файла через url ссылку на него

Tags: python, python-3.x, recaptcha, распознавание-речи

есть такой вопрос по распознаванию аудио файла mp3 по ссылке которую выдает ReCAPTCHA(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) от google.

---

Если посмотреть в Консоль разработчика
,то капча генерирует ссылку на аудио файл который можно скачать перейдя по сгенерированной ссылке.

---

Так вот - возможно ли чтобы библиотека speech recognition распознала текст этого файла.

---

Слышал про библиотеку urllib которая может декодировать файлы. Но без понятия каким образом можно перекодировать так что бы speech recognition это понимал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

А я бы использовал полноценную распознавалку - [воск](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install)

А чтобы файл перекодировать из одного формата в другой - не нашел простого способа. Поиск по github выдает много вариантов, надо смотреть.

Конечно, изящно было бы сервис самого гугла заставить распознавать его голосовую капчу, вроде для этого у гугла есть [такой сервис](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text)

Правда, в комментариях подсказывают, что он платный, но что поделать!

А еще - есть очень простой способ обхода капчи, если задача именно в этом: это сервис https://anti-captcha.com/.
Он тоже платный, но он берет букально центы за распознавание капч, и, что самое главное, это происходит в автоматическом режиме. Там есть примеры, как с ним интегрироваться. А еще есть очень забавная веб - панель, в которой показываются те капчи, которые сейчас распознаются.

Comment: у гугла сервис платный